# Python Image using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt

I am trying to show 2 images using PYQT Numpy format. But the 2nd image comes after 1 image closes. I want to show both the image simultaneously.

```
ImageAddress = 'D:\\Boot.PNG'
ImageItself = Image.open(ImageAddress)
ImageNumpyFormat = np.asarray(ImageItself)
plt.imshow(ImageNumpyFormat)
plt.title('Decision Tree')
plt.axis('off')
plt.draw()
plt.pause(20)
plt.close()
ImageAddress = 'D:\\Internwt.PNG'
ImageItself = Image.open(ImageAddress)
ImageNumpyFormat = np.asarray(ImageItself)
plt.imshow(ImageNumpyFormat)
plt.title('Decision Tree')
plt.axis('off')
plt.draw()
plt.pause(20)
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `plt` comes from [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/matplotlib). Instead of your first `plt.close()`, use `plt.figure(2)` to open a second figure. Also, you probably don't need `plt.draw()` at all, instead, end the program with `plt.show()` so it waits until you close the plots.